# How many intersections does n degree two polynomials have?

Tags: polynomials, intersection-theory

Given $n$ polynomials $f_i(x) = a_i x^2+ b_ix+c_i$, where $a_i, b_i, c_i \in \mathbb{R}$.
And assume that no two polynomials are identical.
The minimum number of intersections is 0 since one can let $\forall i, a_i = a, b_i=b$. And then it's the same polynomial shifted in parallel.

How about the maximum number of intersections?

By intersection, I mean points where at least two $f_i$
vanish.

Comment: at least two, if every $f_i$ vanishes, then the max number should be 2

Comment: That's not what intersection of two polynomials means. An intersection of two polynomials is a point $(x,y)$ where $y=f_i(x) =f_j(x)$.

Comment: i think two vanishes is just saying $f_i(x) - f_j(x) = 0 \exists i, j $, and all vanishes is saying $f_i(x) - f_j(x) = 0 \forall i, j$, which is the same thing.

Comment: Saying that two polynomials vanish at $x$ means $f_i(x) = f_j(x) = 0$ which is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_i(x)=ix^2-\exp(i)$.  $f_i$ and $f_j$ meet at $$x_{ij}^2=\frac{\exp(i)-\exp(j)}{i-j}$$
If any $x_{ij}=x_{kl}$ then the transcendental $e$ would satisfy a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: Can you please expand a bit here? I don't quite follow the claim. How do I interpret it to the maximum number of intersections?

Comment: Any two intersect in two places.  The difference $f_i-f_j$ is quadratic, so that is the most.  There are $n\choose2$ pairs $i,j$ so $2{n\choose2}=n(n-1)$ points in total.  My post explains why they are all distinct